# Why set tableView auto height not working?

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, scrollview

**My Problems:** I'm trying to set auto height to my table cell. However, when I using `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` or `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { return UITableView.automaticDimension }`. As shown on image, I got **0** height for my tableView; but if I set the tableView's height at autoLayout, I can see my tableView again.(which is not right because I want height to be dynamic, the button and the view should at bottom of table view.)
[image]
[image]

**Here is My ViewController Code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var dataSource = ["1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2",]
    
    private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        scrollView.bounces = false
        return scrollView
    }()
    
    private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(TestTabelCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TestTabelCell.identifier)
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        return tableView
    }()
    
    private lazy var moreBtn: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Click for More", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var bottomView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .brown
        return view
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setupUI()
    }

    func setupUI() {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(tableView)
        scrollView.addSubview(moreBtn)
        scrollView.addSubview(bottomView)
        
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        moreBtn.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(tableView.snp.bottom)
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(20)
        }
        
        bottomView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(moreBtn.snp.bottom)
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalTo(390)
            make.height.equalTo(400)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TestTabelCell.identifier, for: indexPath)
        if let cell = cell as? TestTabelCell {
            cell.updateUI(String(indexPath.row))
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        print("print", UITableView.automaticDimension)
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

**and Here is My Cell Code:**

```
class TestTabelCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "ParlorJourneyListCell"
    
    private lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        label.textColor = .black
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            setupUI()
        }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupUI() {
        addSubview(label)
        
        label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(8)
            make.height.equalTo(20)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
    
    func updateUI(_ num: String) {
        label.text = "Test Num: \(num)"
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you add some description... you've shown us what you're doing that is ***not what you want*** -- but you haven't told or shown us what you **DO** want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you're calculating just table view cell height, not table view height itself. You have to recalculate table view height every time `reloadData()` get called. I assume that the cell's autolayout is correct. There are few steps to do:

```swift
func viewDidLoad() {
   ...
   //Added listener to your table view contentSize if changed
   tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
}

//Then override this function to update table view height
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard keyPath == "contentSize" else { return }
    guard
        let newValue = change?[.newKey],
        let newHeight = (newValue as? CGSize)?.height else { return }
    tableView.snp.updateConstraints {
        $0.height.equalTo(newHeight)
    }
}
```

Comment: I try not to use notification, is this the only way to achieve this? And, could you please tell me why I cannot get the height of table view, is that because I use AutoLayout?

Comment: firstly, your code above doesn't show up anything about table view height. Secondly, if you implement as my answer, then your table view will miss the best part `reuse cell`

Comment: thanks, does it means I need to calculate tableView's height manually? I will try.

Comment: yeah, you can try to calculate manually. However, it's hard to handle with dynamic cell than the answer above. Though, you should be aware when your table view height is greater than the screen height. Will it be scroll-forever without reuse cell or there is maximum height value then enable reuse cell. You make a dicision.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your cell's subviews in the contentView of the cell. And make constraints based on contentView.

```
func setupUI() {
    contentView.addSubview(label)
    label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(8)
        make.height.equalTo(20)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
}
```

Change your code like this and try now!

> ```
>     contentView.addSubview(label)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I use tableView's section to solve my problem.

I consider the whole page as a tableView, and **separate the views into 2 sections**, which is: the tableView's part(used to be tableView, now is a section), and the bottomView. And I consider more button as section footer.

Also, I can get tableView's height by using son's answer, but I choose to layout my views in one particular tableView so that I don't need to calculate the height.